# How do I detect purged messages in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, purge

How do I detect the purged channel messages?

The `on_message_delete(message)` event listener does not get called when messages are purged with the `clear` function command.

I need to somehow detect which messages get deleted in a channel preferably without having to create a threaded function that iterates through the channel to see if messages are removed, in this case getting purged every 12 hours by Dyno.

Comment: Hey ! Did you try the [`on_raw_message_delete`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_message_delete) function ?

Comment: Hi DrLarck, I tried it as you suggested but it sadly does not detect purged messages.

Comment: However I found the solution right underneath, thank you! [`on_bulk_message_delete`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_bulk_message_delete) Thank you!